# Get Number of Days of one month and year JAVA

Tags: java

I have a date, I want to get the number of days  of one month of one year for example:

```
GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
calendar.setTime(date);
```

let's assume this date is 04/14/2014, then I would get the number of day of the month 04 In our case is 30 days, how do it ?

thanks

Comment: calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

Comment: Get the first day of the next month and subtract one day

Comment: yes thanks my freinds that's correct calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)